# del operator question regarding commutativity with a scalar

Tags: differential-operators

Is the following true if $f$ is a scalar?

$f\,(\nabla\circ\textbf{B})=f\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}+f\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}+f\frac{\partial B}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}f+\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}f+\frac{\partial B}{\partial z}f=(\nabla\circ\textbf{B})\,f$

Comment: It is true but not what is meant by the operator communting with a scalar $f$.

Comment: @Spencer:  OK, so this is not a true definition of commute... yes, I think I see what you mean.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to determine the commutator of a scalar function with the divergence operator then what you need to compute is,

$$[f,\nabla \cdot]B =  f \nabla \cdot B - \nabla \cdot (fB)  $$